# GET Запрос не работает

Tags: python

Вечер добрый,кодеры. У меня вонизкла проблема. У меня есть такой js код

```
// Load price history
        $J('#pricehistory_container').show();
        $J('#pricehistory').hide();
        $J('#pricehistory_throbber').show();
        $J('#pricehistory_notavailable').hide();
        new Ajax.Request( 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/', {
                method: 'get',
                parameters: {
                    appid: this.m_item.appid,
                    market_hash_name: GetMarketHashName( this.m_item )
                },
                onSuccess: function( transport ) { SellItemDialog.OnPriceHistorySuccess( transport ); },
                onFailure: function( transport ) { SellItemDialog.OnPriceHistoryFailure( transport ); }
        } );
```

Я его взял со стима,когда проверял вкладку network,но это не важно. Мне важно получить эти данные. Я делаю гет запрос на этот юрл через библу requests и мне постоянно возвращает респонс 400,означающий,что это не верный запрос. Почему так происходит?

Python code:

```
import requests
data = {'appid': 730, 'market_hash_name': 'Fracture Case'}
r = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/', data=data)

print(r)
```

Comment: Возможно, потому что в JS используется какой-то хеш, а Вы отправляете строку plain текстом.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду 'market_hash_name'? Нет,там используется дефолтный текст

Comment: *>когда проверял вкладку network,но это не важно* - вообще, важно. Я не знаю js, следовательно, не совсем понимаю, что делает этот кусок кода, а шагов для воспроизведения Вы не привели, следовательно, помочь Вам не могу.

Comment: @AlexaCarra, причем тут вообще `POST` запрос? + У стима в этом плане должен быть `API`. Не надо писать костыльных велосипедов.